# How to get multiple loop in category.php, my scripts becomes madness

Tags: categories, theme-development, loop

I am trying to develop a `category.php` page for my new theme and the loop which I’ve developed shows all posts of my blog and really bad too.

I'm not an expert in WordPress theme development and getting mad because of this thing. I need to show the most recent posts of the selected category, big and different and others with another style.

This is the relevant code:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( array ('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'desc' ) ); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
  <?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => $category->slug, 'showposts' => '5') ); ?>
  <h2><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
  <ul class="thumbs">
  <?php $i = 0; ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php bm_ignorePost($post->ID); ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <a<?php if ( $i == 0 ) : ?> class="first"<?php endif; ?><?php $i++; ?> href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(151,151)  ); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
  <p class="more"><a href="/category/<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">More &raquo;</a></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My recent question but didn't get a reply on the [wordpress.org forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-mad-because-of-wordpress-query_loop-in-categoryphp).

Comment: Please update the question with the related codes you have been trying to make it work.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y0yRFM6G , here is my category.php and it's not a part of any other themes. I just developed that. I'm only 17 and please help me to solve this.

Comment: @MuhammedAshiqueKuthini please, next time post relevant code in the question body.